# Python. Gtk 3. Переместить виджет "Scrolledwindow" выше кнопки в виджете "Notebook"

Tags: python, gtk

[image: Проблема]

Как в данном примере переместить *Gtk.Scrolledwindow* выше кнопки. То есть, поместить *Scrolledwindow* на место кнопки, а кнопку на место *Scrolledwindow* (**как указано на изображении**)?

Кнопка располагается в объекте *Gtk.Notebook*.

***GTK 3***

```
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk

class app:
   def __init__(self):
       window_main = gtk.Window()
       window_main.set_size_request(gdk.Screen.get_default().get_width(),0)
       window_main.set_name("window_main")
       window_main.move(0,0)
       window_main.set_keep_above(True)
       window_main.set_resizable(False)
       window_main.set_decorated(False)
       window_main.set_border_width(0)
       window_main.connect("destroy",lambda e: gtk.main_quit())

       box_main = gtk.HBox()

       scrolledwindow_categories = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
       scrolledwindow_categories.set_policy(
           gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC,
           gtk.PolicyType.NEVER
        )
       scrolledwindow_categories.set_size_request(20,20)

       viewport_categories = gtk.Viewport()
       viewport_categories.add(box_main)
       scrolledwindow_categories.add(viewport_categories)
       window_main.add(scrolledwindow_categories)

       notebook_categories = gtk.Notebook()
       box_main.add(notebook_categories)

       for i in range(20):
           button = gtk.Button("Button")
           notebook_categories.append_page(button,gtk.Label("Text"))

       window_main.show_all()
       gtk.main()

app()
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос , Где должен находится `ScrolledWindow` ? Уточните версию gtk (gtk2 или gtk3 )?

Comment: Да и использование `Viewport` вместе с `ScrolledWindow` не нужно. Так как  `ScrolledWindow` уже содержит `Viewport`.  `Viewport` используется с элементами у которых нет прокрутки . такие как `HBox`

Comment: @Yaroslav поправил.

Comment: По исхоному коду, Вы создаете `Window`, в `Window` помешаете `ScrolledWindow` в этом объекте создается система прокрутки, в `ScrolledWindow` помешаете объект `Box` и в объект `Box` помешаете  `Notebook` , а уже в `Notebook` У вас находится кнопка. поэтому область прокрутки находится внизу и с ее помошью пожно манипулировать вложеными объектами. Визуально вы ее не перенесете так как кнопка находится внутри `ScrolledWindow`. Поэтому Еще вопрос Какие объекты должны быть внутри `ScrolledWindow` ?

Comment: @Yaroslav лучше я постараюсь реализовать это без `Scrolledwindow`: через кнопки и `vadjustment`.